# Place a null at the beginning of an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a code that turns array into array objects

```
const thisArray = ['1', '2'];
```

Below is my function that converts it:

```
function macsFunction(codes){
  const mappedObjects = codes.map(code => {
    return {
    '0': Number(code),
    '1': 'Car'
     };
  });
 return mappedObjects;
}


const thisSay = macsFunction(thisArray);

console.log(thisSay);
```

The result is like this:

```
[ { '0': 5, '1': 'Car' }, { '0': 13, '1': 'Car' } ]
```

Now it's been a long hours i wanted to achieve something like :

```
[null, { '0': 5, '1': 'Car' }, { '0': 13, '1': 'Car' } ]
```

I want to place a `null` at the beginning of the array. But I've tried `concat`, `fill`, `unshift`. It doesn't work. Happy to see if someone could help.

Comment: `mappedObjects.unshift(null)`

Comment: "it doesnt work" isnt accurate. what happens? is it an error? wrong index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.unshift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) which adds one or more elements to the beginning of an array:

```js
const thisArray = ['1', '2'];

function macsFunction(codes){
  const mappedObjects = codes.map(code => {
    return {
    '0': Number(code),
    '1': 'Car'
     };
  });
 mappedObjects.unshift(null);
 return mappedObjects;
}


const thisSay = macsFunction(thisArray);

console.log(thisSay);
```

Comment: golly i wasn't using the unshift in the right manner. Until you showed up.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the unshift method to add something to the beginning of an array.

Documentation can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift

Comment: Don't make posts with just a link, instead explain what the link is about